# add view to linearlayout on a circle drawn in canvas

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have drawn a circle using canvas draw method. Now I want to add a view on circumference of circle. I can get coordinate of circle but totally lost how to add view to that coordinate.

Code is as below -

```
public class CircleView2 extends LinearLayout {

    private int centerX, centerY;
    private float fixedRadius = 30;
    private Paint paint;
    private Logger logger;
    private Context context;
    TextView textView;

    public CircleView2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        doInit(context);

    }

    public CircleView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        doInit(context);
    }

    private void doInit(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        logger = new Logger(context);

        fixedRadius = 30;

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(227, 73, 90));

        textView = new TextView(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        centerX = w / 2;
        centerY = h / 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, fixedRadius + 160, paint);


        double x = centerX + (fixedRadius + 160) * Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(45.0));
        double y = centerY + (fixedRadius + 160) * Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(45.0));

        logger.debug(x + "");
        logger.debug(y + "");

        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setText("AAA");        
        textView.draw(canvas);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    }
}
```

This draws circle just fine. But can't add textview. `textview.draw(canvas)` should add that to view, right ?  How to add textview to view and that to at calculated coordinates ?

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: extent ViewGroup and override its onLatout method calling layout() for each child

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @Jovan This is quite old question. But yes I solved this issue at some level back then. It had some issues which I don't remember clearly but give it a try. Code is posted there http://pastebin.com/f3gxTY2K

Comment: @SachinGutte thanks for this. I managed to do it myself. I had problems with calculating proper size for some reason. I'm sure that this will get handy to somebody. Nice solution. :)